# Follow steps in dissassembly after application start

Tags: disassembly, windows, debugging

I am new to reverse engineering so this seems like a very basic issue, and still I was not able to find an answer to it myself yet. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

I am on Windows, I disassembled an exe file using "PE Explorer". For now, my process was to somehow, mostly by trial and error, identify the machine code steps I want to change in the dissasembly, then make the necessary change by opening the same exe in a hex editor, finding the same instruction and changing it there.

(Side note here: This two step process is quite inefficient. Is there a program you can recommend where I can combine both steps in one go, or at least side by side?)

While this has worked for me so far, I believe there must be a better way than doing this by trial and error and manually trying to identify the functions in the machine code. Is there? Particularly, is there a way to run a program (exe) and in parallel follow the steps in the dissasembly (ideally slowed down..)?

Thank you.

Comment: Use a debugger like *[OllyDbg](http://www.ollydbg.de)* which can patch executables.

Comment: cdb -c "bp $exentry;g" <yourexe> or windbg -Q -c "bp $exentry;g" <your exe"  will break on WinMainCrt . etc etc (the Address of Entry point in PeHeader)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Particularly, is there a way to run a program (exe) and in parallel
>   follow the steps in the dissasembly (ideally slowed down..)?

Yes, the type of tool you're describing is called a "debugger".

Some popular debuggers for Windows are:

- [OllyDbg](http://www.ollydbg.de/version2.html)
- [IDA Pro](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/index.shtml)'s debugger
- [x64dbg](http://x64dbg.com/)

There are [plenty of others](http://www.woodmann.com/collaborative/tools/index.php/Category:Debuggers), but these are some of the most user-friendly.

Comment: Thanks Jason. Will one of those allow me to make direct changes in the machine code and save back to the same exe? Also, which is your personal favorite?

Comment: OllyDbg v2.01 allows it. You can use an extra plugin for IDA Pro to allow it. Not sure about x64dbg since I so rarely use it. As for my personal favorite, it depends on the requirements. For user-mode x86 debugging on Windows, I use OllyDbg. For user-mode x64 debugging on Windows, I use x64dbg. For kernel-mode debugging on Windows and for user-mode and kernel-mode debugging on non-Windows platforms, I use IDA Pro's debugger.